# {current_time format="%Y"} not working with Low Variables

Tags: low-variables

I've got a low variable which is correctly parsing channel entries tags, but for some reason will not parse {current_time format="%Y"} no matter what settings I use (early parsing on/off). All it outputs is the raw code for that tag.

please advise

Comment: What syntax are you using: variable or tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to do with the good old parse order. To get around it use the short version of the tag together with early parsing and it should work so simply {my_var} instead of e.g. {exp:low_variables:single var="my_var"}

Comment: Thanks - I generally prefer to use the exp:low_variables tag as I can pass stuff through wiht preparse when needed. Fortunately there's no need in this case.